# Get latest tag in branch with JGit

Tags: java, groovy, jgit

I am trying to get the JGit equivalent of the command

```
git describe --match "[0-9]*.[0-9]*.[0-9]*" --abbrev=0 --tags $(git rev-list --tags --branches=master --max-count=1)
```

I have tried getting all the tags in the project and then finding the greatest tag in the branch via the BranchListCommand, but that is to slow.

I am stuck and I cannot find anything that help via my searches.

Does anyone have any idea how to do the intended result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch all tags and then walk the commits on the branch and check for each commit if there is a tag for this ref.

i.e. fetch all tags via:

```
git.tagList().call()
```

then fetch all commits of the branch via:

```
git.log().add(repository.resolve(BRANCH)).call()
```

And then for each commit check if a tag exists at this ref.

When run on a fairly large repository on a branch with more than 60k commits, walking all the commits this way is done in 1.2 seconds.

```
Had 60843 commits overall on branch remotes/origin/master, iteration took 1200ms
```

An even larger branch takes 8 seconds when walking 380k commits.

```
Had 388613 commits overall on branch remotes/origin/master, iteration took 8261ms
```

I have added a ready-to-run snippet to the [jgit-cookboot](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/), see [ListTagsOnBranch.java](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/porcelain/ListTagsOnBranch.java)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the previous answer, I'd like to share my solution (JGit 6.6.0.202305301015-r). Essentially, simply mapping the `tagList()` did not work for me because the resulting Refs were unpeeled. The solution was to peel them before grouping them into a map. The JavaDoc of RefDatabase.peel states:

> Peel a possibly unpeeled reference by traversing the annotated tags.
> If the reference cannot be peeled (as it does not refer to an annotated tag) >the peeled id stays null, but Ref.isPeeled() will be true.
> Implementors should check Ref.isPeeled() before performing any additional work >effort.

### Code

```
try (final var git = Git.open(new File("/path/to/your/repository"))) {
    final var repository = git.getRepository();
    final var refDatabase = repository.getRefDatabase();
    
    // Create a map of peeled references.
    final var tags = refDatabase.getRefsByPrefix(R_TAGS).stream().map(ref -> {
        try {
            return refDatabase.peel(ref);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
        }
    }).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ref -> {
        final var peeledObjectId = ref.getPeeledObjectId();
        return peeledObjectId == null ? ref.getObjectId() : peeledObjectId;
    }, Collectors.mapping(ref -> ref, Collectors.toList())));

    // Collect the matching tag(s) into a chronological list
    final var result = StreamSupport.stream(git.log()
        .add(repository.resolve(branch))
        .call().spliterator(), false)
        .map(rev -> tags.get(rev.getId()))
        .filter(refs -> refs != null)
        .toList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this question is the first Google result for the phrase `jgit get latest tag`, I'm posting a simple solution to get the latest tag for the current branch:

```java
git.describe().setTags(true).setAbbrev(0).call()
```